# how to pass scope variable value as FormName to ng-click param and get FormName.$valid and FormName.$dirty view angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

how to pass scope variable as 'FormName' of ng-click parameter to  get FormName.$valid and FormName.$dirty in view angularjs.

Example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Main', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.FormName = 'FormNameValidation';
    $scope.showFormValidation = function(statusValid, statusDirty)
    {
     $scope.FormNameValidationStatus = statusValid;
     $scope.FormNameDirtyStatus = statusDirty;
    }

}]);

<form name="FormName" novalidate>
    <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
        <button type="button" ng-click="showFormValidation(FormName.$valid, FormName.$dirty)">Click</button>
        {{FormNameValidationStatus}}
        {{FormNameDirtyStatus}}
    </div>
</form>
```

**Output: undefined undefined**

Comment: In the from you don't have any input field and validation rule then how the form will be dirty or valid?

Comment: The form element is declared outside the bounds of your ng-app as well so I don't think angular will be aware of it.  You should move the form inside the `<div ng-app='my-app' ...` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the form element is not enclosed within the element that defines ngApp directive.  If you rearrange the elements so that the form is a descendant of the div with the ng-app attribute you should get what you want

```js
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('Main', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.FormName = 'FormNameValidation';
      $scope.showFormValidation = function(statusValid, statusDirty) {
        $scope.FormNameValidationStatus = statusValid;
        $scope.FormNameDirtyStatus = statusDirty;
      }

    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Form State</h1>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Main">
    <form name="FormName" novalidate="">
      <button type="button" ng-click="showFormValidation(FormName.$valid, FormName.$dirty)">Click</button>
      {{FormNameValidationStatus}} {{FormNameDirtyStatus}}
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```